# How break line while using float/in-line without using <br> in html?

Tags: html, css, layout

I have three sections in the same line: GPS TRACKING, VOLTAGE INDICATOR and SPEEDOMETER.

I want to go to the line below those three sections. To do this I use a bunch of `<br>` tags because if I don't use them my "THIS IS THE TEXT" will be placed next to speedometer heading and the rectangle below it.

How do I avoid using the `<br>` tags?

```css
.baris {
  float: left;
  width: 30%;
  margin-left: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.rectangle {
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="baris">
  <h1>GPS TRACKING</h1>
  <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m8!1m3!1d5635.9118897681665!2d101.7364976658753!3d2.759584154684244!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x31cdc0f650a70f95%3A0x11a68c649e6f0e9d!2sSepang%20F1%20Circuit%20Pit%20Lane!5e0!3m2!1sid!2sid!4v1592872331420!5m2!1sid!2sid"
    width="400" height="300" frameborder="0" style="border:0;" allowfullscreen="" aria-hidden="false" tabindex="0"></iframe>
</div>
<div class="baris">
  <h1>VOLTAGE INDICATOR</h1>
  <div class="rectangle"></div>
</div>
<div class="baris">
  <h1>SPEEDOMETER</h1>
  <div class="rectangle"></div>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<p style="text-align: center;">THIS IS THE TEXT</p>
```

Comment: Hi Sam! I suggest you read a bit about how to layout html, which is the problem you currently have. It is essential to write better html & css code and will save you a lot of time in the future. This could be a place to get a good ground knowledge: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Introduction. For this layout problem I would use the flexbox model: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try wrapping your elements in a flex container set to `display: inline-flex`. Flexbox can help with your layout and is a lot easier to work with than float.

Further, setting the `justify-content: space-evenly` will space your items evenly with the available width from the parent element. Feel free to check the docs for other options you can pass to `justify-content`.

I think this example from MDN will help you a lot (and the layout looks similar to what you are trying to replicate): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox.

```css
.flexcontainer {
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.baris {
  float: left;
  width: 30%;
  margin-left: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.rectangle {
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class='flexcontainer'>
    <div class="baris">
      <h1>GPS TRACKING</h1>
      <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m8!1m3!1d5635.9118897681665!2d101.7364976658753!3d2.759584154684244!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x31cdc0f650a70f95%3A0x11a68c649e6f0e9d!2sSepang%20F1%20Circuit%20Pit%20Lane!5e0!3m2!1sid!2sid!4v1592872331420!5m2!1sid!2sid"
        width="400" height="300" frameborder="0" style="border:0;" allowfullscreen="" aria-hidden="false" tabindex="0"></iframe>
    </div>
    <div class="baris">
      <h1>VOLTAGE INDICATOR</h1>
      <div class="rectangle"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="baris">
      <h1>SPEEDOMETER</h1>
      <div class="rectangle"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <p style="text-align: center;">THIS IS THE TEXT</p>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your text is under a **float** element, you need to clear it, one way to do it is to clear it in your text body

```css
.baris {
  float: left;
  width: 30%;
  margin-left: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.rectangle {
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.my-copy {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="baris">
  <h1>GPS TRACKING</h1>
  <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m8!1m3!1d5635.9118897681665!2d101.7364976658753!3d2.759584154684244!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x31cdc0f650a70f95%3A0x11a68c649e6f0e9d!2sSepang%20F1%20Circuit%20Pit%20Lane!5e0!3m2!1sid!2sid!4v1592872331420!5m2!1sid!2sid"
    width="400" height="300" frameborder="0" style="border:0;" allowfullscreen="" aria-hidden="false" tabindex="0"></iframe>
</div>
<div class="baris">
  <h1>VOLTAGE INDICATOR</h1>
  <div class="rectangle"></div>
</div>
<div class="baris">
  <h1>SPEEDOMETER</h1>
  <div class="rectangle"></div>
</div>
<p class="my-copy" style="text-align: center;">THIS IS THE TEXT</p>
```

#### References:

https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/